# Finding coinciding points in point shapefile using ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, table

I have a point SHP with some points overlapping, they have the exact same X & Y coordinates, I want to extract these points to a new table.

I tried FindSimilar python script but no results.

Comment: Do you want to move both instances of coincident points to new table or just one (If one, how do you determine which one?)?

Comment: Sometimes it's more than two points overlapping but 3/4/5/6 points that have same coordinates. I would like to get all points that are overlapping. So the points to ignore are the ones with unique X AND Y coordinates.

Comment: Collect Events tool will find all coincidental points and give you a count of them in the newly created layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method of finding features on top of features is:

1. In the layer attribute table create a new x and y (both fields type DOUBLE) and right click on each and calculate each geometry (x and y values or centroid values)
2. Create another type TEXT field called concat and and field calculate the x and y field values together
3. Next, summarize the concat field (right click it in attribute table and select summarize option and take all default settings).  This will provide a count table of all overlapping features by xy concatenation.
4. Finally, join the result of the summarize table to the layer table by concat field.  All values with count > 1 are coincident features.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Collect Events" tool. The output feature class or shapefile will have a column called "ICOUNT" which is the number of points at each location from the input points. ICOUNT = 1 is 1 point, ICOUNT = 2 is 2 points, etc.